# Plot Matplotlib Graph with Marked New Highs

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, trendline

So I was wondering whether there is an easy way to plot a graph with matplotlib.pyplot as a Line with marked new highs.. As in [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDREg.jpg) (as a line).

I could'nt find anything on the docs or elsewhere. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of something built-in, have you had a go implementing this yourself? You could always track these events outside of matplotlib and plot as two series.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, plotting two series, but wanted to check if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: Honestly, I'd say that was probably the most elegant way :) It's a bit of a fringe feature (I would imagine people would have many different minor tweaks they would want to make) so it makes more sense to build it explicitly from the base tools given.

Comment: I would use a pandas expanding window to compute this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions